# Timeout expired.The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using `C#` with  `Visual Studio` and `MySql`. I have a button in my code that has it own method. When its over it calls another method from a `Class`. I already edit `timeout` of command and connection. This method insert dates to a table. I insert dates in this same table a second time, it reads the last ID and make a `"id"` increasing +1.
The First time the dates come over 20.000 the second times it goes to 40.000++.
Is that a problem?

```
            public void PendenciaAssociado()
                {

            #region LeituraDosDados
            MySqlConnection Con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strConexaoDestino"].ConnectionString);
            MySqlCommand Cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            Cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000;
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Cmd.Connection = Con;           
            string sql = "SELECT matricula,dt_nascimento,cpf,rg,celular,mail,profissao,dt_insercao,usr_insercao from Associados";
            Cmd.CommandText = sql;           
            Con.Open();
            MySqlDataReader dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();            
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            Con.Close();
            Con.Dispose();

            #endregion

            #region Variaveis
            int matricula, profissao;
            DateTime dt_nascimento, dt_insercao;
            string cpf, rg, celular, mail, usr_insercao, pendencia;
            #endregion


            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {

                matricula = Convert.ToInt32(row["matricula"]);
                dt_nascimento = Convert.ToDateTime(row["dt_nascimento"]);
                cpf = row["cpf"].ToString();
                rg = row["rg"].ToString();
                celular = row["celular"].ToString();
                mail = row["mail"].ToString();
                profissao = Convert.ToInt32(row["profissao"]);
                dt_insercao = Convert.ToDateTime(row["dt_insercao"]);
                usr_insercao = row["usr_insercao"].ToString();

                if (profissao == 0)
                {
                    pendencia = "Favor Verificar a Profissao do Associado";
                    InserePendencias(matricula, dt_nascimento, cpf, rg, celular, mail, profissao, dt_insercao, usr_insercao, pendencia);
                }
                if (dt_nascimento.ToString() == "01/01/1980 00:00:00")
                {
                    pendencia = "Favor Verificar a Data de Nascimento do Associado";
                    InserePendencias(matricula, dt_nascimento, cpf, rg, celular, mail, profissao, dt_insercao, usr_insercao, pendencia);
                }
                if (cpf == "00000000000")
                {
                    pendencia = "Favor Verificar o CPF do Associado";
                    InserePendencias(matricula, dt_nascimento, cpf, rg, celular, mail, profissao, dt_insercao, usr_insercao, pendencia);
                }
                if (rg == "0000000000")
                {
                    pendencia = "Favor Verificar o RG do Associado";
                    InserePendencias(matricula, dt_nascimento, cpf, rg, celular, mail, profissao, dt_insercao, usr_insercao, pendencia);
                }
                if (celular == "")
                {
                    pendencia = "Favor Verificar o Celular do Associado";
                    InserePendencias(matricula, dt_nascimento, cpf, rg, celular, mail, profissao, dt_insercao, usr_insercao, pendencia);
                }
                if (mail == "")
                {
                    pendencia = "Favor Verificar o Email do Associado";
                    InserePendencias(matricula, dt_nascimento, cpf, rg, celular, mail, profissao, dt_insercao, usr_insercao, pendencia);
                }
            }
        }

        int contador = 0, aux, aux2;
        public void InserePendencias(int matricula, DateTime data_nasci, string cpf, string rg, string celular, string email, int profissao, DateTime data_insercao, string usuario, string pendencia)
        {

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strConexaoDestino"].ConnectionString);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            string seleciona = "SELECT MAX(codigo) as codigo FROM pendencias";
            cmd.CommandText = seleciona;
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            con.Close();
            if (contador == 0)
            {
                contador++;
                aux2 = contador;
            }
            else if (contador != 0)
            {
                contador++;
                aux = contador;
            }



            cmd.Connection = con;                
            string query = "INSERT INTO  pendencias (codigo,matricula,pendencia,dt_insercao,usr_insercao) VALUES(" +
                           "@codigo,@matricula,@pendencia,@dt_insercao,@usr_insercao)";
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@codigo", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = contador;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@matricula", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = matricula;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@pendencia", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = pendencia;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@dt_insercao", MySqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = data_nasci;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@usr_insercao", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = usuario;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

OK - Im not posting as an answer but as I had too much to say for a comment.. If I get an answer I can edit it in.. So, this is a LONG comment!

So the first thing I see is:

```
       if (profissao == 0) 
        { 
            pendencia = "Favor Verificar a Profissao do Associado"; 
            InserePendencias(matricula, dt_nascimento, cpf, rg, celular, mail, profissao, dt_insercao, usr_insercao, pendencia); 
        } 
        if (dt_nascimento.ToString() == "01/01/1980 00:00:00") 
        { 
            pendencia = "Favor Verificar a Data de Nascimento do Associado"; 
            InserePendencias(matricula, dt_nascimento, cpf, rg, celular, mail, profissao, dt_insercao, usr_insercao, pendencia); 
        } 
        if (cpf == "00000000000") 
        { 
            pendencia = "Favor Verificar o CPF do Associado"; 
            InserePendencias(matricula, dt_nascimento, cpf, rg, celular, mail, profissao, dt_insercao, usr_insercao, pendencia); 
        } 
        if (rg == "0000000000") 
        { 
            pendencia = "Favor Verificar o RG do Associado"; 
            InserePendencias(matricula, dt_nascimento, cpf, rg, celular, mail, profissao, dt_insercao, usr_insercao, pendencia); 
        } 
        if (celular == "") 
        { 
            pendencia = "Favor Verificar o Celular do Associado"; 
            InserePendencias(matricula, dt_nascimento, cpf, rg, celular, mail, profissao, dt_insercao, usr_insercao, pendencia); 
        } 
        if (mail == "") 
        { 
            pendencia = "Favor Verificar o Email do Associado"; 
            InserePendencias(matricula, dt_nascimento, cpf, rg, celular, mail, profissao, dt_insercao, usr_insercao, pendencia); 
        }
```

Where the reality is, you want to set pendecia to a value, and call exactly the same call .. could really use some code simplification there.

Each time you're running it, you're doubling the number of records.. so the first time you had 10, by the end you have 20.. so the next time you have 20 and end with 40... Is this what you really wanted?

if your first 10 all needed this function running, you arent preventing them from being included the second time round by updating them. So, its not like you then evaluate only the 10 added lines, but you would evaulate all 20 lines, producing the second set of 10 again - as you did the first time round, as well as any new values form the previously added 10... Kinda a form of infinite loopish type behavior, but with inserting into a db instead of just playing with values.

Comment: Thanks for answer me BugFinder... But tell me, how I fix it? As you can see i used a bunch of "if" I need to verify wich fields are empty and for each empty field i INSERT it on a table... I dont want to do what you said its happening, 10-20-40-80... How may I fix it ? and add only 10 values ?
Thanks for the attention !

Comment: Well thats the thing, Ive tried to explain what your code does - YOU now need to work out how to explain/code what you meant, not what its doing. Is there a unique ID? would you not just want to "Update" the row, rather than add a new one?

Comment: Then you still need to do something to the old one to stop it being processed again.